# I got Cannot read property 'name_restaurant' of undefined When I tried to return thedetails of each restaurant on my detail page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've created a dynamic routing for a ProductDetail page (each Restaurant has its own details that should be shown on this page). the routing is working but I don't get any data and I can't figure out the right way to get data from firestore by the Id of each restaurant.

**PS:** the product details are rendering in the console but the problem still how to display to the detailpage

**ProductDetail.js**

```
import { firestore } from "../../../../../fire";
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {useState} from "react";
import {Fragment} from "react";

function ProductDetail() {
  const {productId}= useParams();
  
  const [product,setProduct]=useState();

  useEffect( () =>  {
 
   firestore
     .collection("Restaurants")
     .doc(productId).get()
     .then( doc => {
       console.log(doc.data());
       setProduct(doc.data());
    
       
     });
     
   }, () => {

 }
 );
 
  return (
    
    <div className="col-12">
      <div className="card">
        <h1>{product.name_restaurant}  </h1>
        <p>Price:$</p>
        {/* <p>{product.email}</p> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  }
export default ProductDetail;
```

**this my console : all details of the restaurant are returned**
[image]

**Still cannot return details on my page**

[image]

**I got this error**
[image]

Comment: try place this code this.setstate({Restaurants:product}) into  .then( doc => {

Comment: And be careful. You declare the product in the .then function as an array and set the state for it, but then you try to get the property as from the object <h1> {product.name_restaurant} </h1>

Comment: @AlexandrKiseloy  I've edited the code ..I was just testing with an array but I got the same error mentioned     I've tried your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't worked

Comment: Oh! Offcorse! Add check before access prop. <h1> {product && product.name_restaurant}</h1>. On first render product eq null

Comment: At the beginning, data was displayed but then I got this error Error: ProductDetail(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.  @AlexandrKiseloy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLVED** By adding an ? to product and that's to check undefined `{product?.name_restaurant}`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you first render the component your product state variable is null, then you make the API call in the useEffect, your state variable is populated and the component is re-rendered, but at that point, you already have the error. To fix it, you  just have to render your markup when the product is ready to be rendered (not null)

```js
return product ? (
    <div className="col-12">
      <div className="card">
        <h1>{product.name_restaurant}  </h1>
        <p>Price:$</p>
        {/* <p>{product.email}</p> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : <div>Loading...</div>;
```

Comment: At the beginning data was displayed but then I got this error **Error: ProductDetail(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.** @ludwiguer

Comment: Ah yes, because you are not returning anything if the product is null, I modified the example with a common pattern on how to deal wit this